# finding "orphan" files in website structure

Tags: php, html, mysql, string, directory

I have a site that I've built that is connected to a mysql database. I have items (listed in the database) that correspond to pictures. Database structure is:

```
Item_num    Description    Price    Available
```

Item_num is a unique alphanumeric (A001).
In my images folder, I have several photos of A001, labeled:

```
A001_full.jpg
A001_thumb.jpg
A001_model.jpg
```

This is fairly consistent. Some pictures don't have the _model version, but all have the _thumb and _full versions.  Unfortunately, I added a bunch of pictures then abandoned the site. As i'm bringing it back online, a lot of those pictures do not have an SQL entry to match them. What I would like to do is this:

1. Import the directory listing of the images (../images)
2. grab the first part of the file name (before the '_'), thinking strtok for that
3. use that token to query against the Item_num key in the database
4. if that key is found, move to the next file
5. if that key is not found, output the token to the page

i'm really unsure of the directory listing and how to handle that, and how to run multiple repeated queries to the database. I'm used to running one query then using the results from that. Any help on this would be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you use the shell on the server? This may be easier to do with a shell script.

Comment: probably not. running this local on Win7 with apache and mysql. want something dynamic so i can make adjustments of a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with a single query, and then loop through the results.  It will be faster than running one query per entry.  Something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT Item_num FROM table";
```

Then we'll assume you've dumped the result an indexed array where each element is the value of `Item_num` for each row into `$result` (the specifics of creating this array may depend on how you're interacting with the database):

```
// Loop through all images
foreach ( glob( '../images/*' ) as $image ) {
    // Get the portion of the name before the underscore
    list( $image_item ) = explode( '_', $image );

    // Compare this to all of the return values
    if ( !in_array( $image_item, $result )) {
        // The image is not in the database
    }
}
```

Comment: A little better would be to make the database results the keys of the `$result` array instead of the values. Then you can use `if(!isset($result[$image_item]))`

Comment: @nick coons when i try your code i get `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\possible_worlds\structure\missingdata.php on line 48`  $result should be an array already
`$query="SELECT Item_Num FROM laf_total";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("couldn't execute query");`

Comment: @BrianFager, parameter 2 (`$result`) should be an array after you've populated it with contents from the database.. did you do that first?

Comment: @NickCoons - I think i was editing when you last posted. yes, as you can see above $result is an sql query which should (if my understanding is correct) make it an array.

Comment: @BrianFager, `$result=mysql_query($query)` means that `$result` is a resource, not an array. You'd have to parse through it with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get the values and create an array.